# Project Management Templates

Tags: templates

In the interest of not reinventing the wheel, are there any useful websites with collections of good samples of various deliverables (project charters, status reports, communication plans, RACI matrixes, post-mortem templates, etc.)

Comment: Be careful, in most cases templates and checklists are evil. I would suggest to stay away from them as much as possible

Comment: Why do you say that?  Pilots and surgeons use checklists all the time... they free your mind from focusing on repetitive minutia so you can devote that brain space to creative thinking.  I strongly recommend reading "The Checklist Manifesto: How to Get Things Right" by Atul Gawande (http://www.amazon.com/Checklist-Manifesto-How-Things-Right/dp/0805091742)

Comment: @yegor256: 'evil' is a bit harsh.  @Sean Earp: I think yegor is saying that because other peoples templates and checklists often contain way too much 'noise' - items that you & your project care nothing about.  In the end, you can spend as much time simplifying a template you downloaded as you would if you just made it from scratch.  In the end, it comes down to your work style, would you rather tear-down or build-up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a list of Project Management Templates broken out into categories like planning, executing, controlling, closing, and other project documentation:

[Project Management Docs - Templates](http://www.projectmanagementdocs.com/templates.html)

Here are just a few highlights:

- Project Management Plan Template - This defines PM approach, scope, milestones, schedules, communication management, and many other details of the project, in a Word/Open Office document.
- Expense Report - Spreadsheet to list item by item costs incurred on the project.
- Risk Register
- Communication Management
- Status Reports
- Cost Management - Approach, measuring costs, define reporting format, cost change control process, etc.
- Many more.

This seems very thorough and worth checking out.  The templates are free to use.

Answer (score 2):

Some other resources I have found... It looks like Microsoft provides quite a few templates here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/CT001226193.aspx, and Key Consulting has a number of templates here: http://www.consulting.ky/free_project_management_templates.php